# Word XML document duplicated footer

Tags: xml, ms-word, ms-office, openxml

I tried to create footer in MS Word document from [this solution](http://mvark.blogspot.ru/2010/09/how-to-dynamically-generate-word.html). 
It's ok, footer looks great, but text from footer duplicated in document body.
How can i remove this?

Screenshot of document: http://d.pr/i/GR4U

And code of document:

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <xml>
                <w:WordDocument>
                    <w:View>Print</w:View>
                    <w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>
                    <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
                </w:WordDocument>
            </xml>
        <![endif]-->
        <style xmlns="" type="text/css" media="all">
            body {font-size: 100%;}
            h1.normal {color: #000 !important; width: 75%;}
            .content_block {margin-right: 3%; width: 74%;}
            div#documentBody {margin-top: 31px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
            div.incut-head span.incut-head-control {font-weight: bold;}
            div.docChainList {font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px; margin: 7px 0 0; padding: 10px;}
            table.author-tbl {width: 40%;}
            div.page-box {width: 100%;}
            div.page-wrapper .doc-page .content {font-size: 14px;}
            pre {font-family: sans-serif;word-wrap: break-word;}

            div.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, p.MsoFooter{
                margin:0in;
                margin-bottom:.0001pt;
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
                font-size:12.0pt;
            }


            <!-- /* Style Definitions */
                @page Section1{
                    size:8.5in 11.0in;
                    margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ;
                    mso-footer: f1;
                    mso-footer-margin:.5in;
                }

                div.Section1{
                    page:Section1;
                }
            -->
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Section1">
        <div xmlns="" class="content_block">
            <div class="above-header"></div>
            <h1 class="normal">Header of document</h1>
            <div id="documentBody" class="content-common">
                <p>Document body text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div xmlns="" style="mso-element:footer" id="f1">
        <p class="MsoFooter">
            Copyright, 2013
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution [here](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-dynamically-generate-word.html).
Just pay attention on how the Word HTML is written.
It's just that I didn't want to take credit of it (anyway I corrected some syntax errors)... this is the text:

```
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
    <style>
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter
{
margin:0in;
margin-bottom:.0001pt;
mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
font-size:12.0pt;
}
<style>

<!-- /* Style Definitions */

@page Section1
{
size:8.5in 11.0in; 
margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ;
mso-header-margin:.5in;
mso-header:h1;
mso-footer: f1; 
mso-footer-margin:.5in;
}

div.Section1
{
page:Section1;
}

table#hrdftrtbl
{
margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" style='tab-interval: .5in'>
    <div class="Section1">
        <h1>
            Time and tide wait for none</h1>
        The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ... ...
        <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style='mso-element: header' id="h1">
                        <p class="MsoHeader" style='text-align: center'>Confidential</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style='mso-element: footer' id="f1">
                        <p class="MsoFooter">
                            Draft <span style='mso-tab-count: 2'></span><span style='mso-field-code: "" PAGE ""'>
                            </span>of <span style='mso-field-code: "" NUMPAGES ""'></span>
                            </p>
                    </div>
                </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it puts a header and footer sections to the document, the text between "div class section" and "table id='hrdftrtbl'... " is the HTML text of the content you need to display.

The only thing I'd need, is the code to insert an image in the header/footer section (s). I tried to insert a base64 image ( FAIL), to insert a URL ( FAIL)

Comment: Please try to explain What is in that link.

Comment: yea, so that when the link is broken, we still can see the essential information..

Comment: This is the best solution. It not only hides the page number, but also any text such as "Page ... of ...". As as side note, with Word 2010 and 2013, the duplicated footer only appears when you print or preview the print.

I tried doing the same by wrapping the footer in a div or by trying to style it with CSS, all to no avail. After hours of work, the table solution above works like a charm.